# One click handler for multiple buttons in stackpanel

Tags: class, for-loop, button, click, switch-statement

I have following xaml:

```
<GroupBox x:Name="GroupBoxInworp" IsEnabled="True" Header="Inworp" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,120,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelInworp" Button.Click="button_Click">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0">
                <Button x:Name="btnTweeEuro" Margin="10" MinWidth="220" Content="2" Click="btnTweeEuro_Click"></Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnEenEuro" Margin="10" MinWidth="220" Content="1" Click="btnEenEuro_Click"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0">
                <Button x:Name="btnVijftigEurocent" Margin="10" MinWidth="100" Content="50" Click="btnVijftigEurocent_Click"></Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnTwintigEurocent" Margin="10" MinWidth="100" Content="20" Click="btnTwintigEurocent_Click"></Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnTienEurocent" Margin="10" MinWidth="100" Content="10" Click="btnTienEurocent_Click"></Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnVijfEurocent" Margin="10" MinWidth="100" Content="5" Click="btnVijfEurocent_Click"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5">
                <Label Content="Huidige inworp:" MinWidth="160"></Label>
                <Label x:Name="lblHuidigeInworp" Content="" MinWidth="300" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"></Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
```

I have following code:

```
private void GeldClick(decimal Inworp)
    {
        TotaalInworp += Inworp;
        lblHuidigeInworp.Content = String.Format("€ {0}", TotaalInworp); 
    }

    private void btnTweeEuro_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GeldClick(2.00M);
    }

    private void btnEenEuro_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GeldClick(1.00M);
    }

    private void btnVijftigEurocent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GeldClick(0.50M);
    }

    private void btnTwintigEurocent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GeldClick(0.20M);
    }

    private void btnTienEurocent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GeldClick(0.10M);
    }

    private void btnVijfEurocent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GeldClick(0.05M);
    }
```

I want to create one handler for all click events with a for or a switch.

The handler would be like

```
StackPanelInworp.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(button_Click));
```

I also want to create a class, in which i can place the event handler with the for or switch. There are 6 buttons.

How can this be accomplished? Also, it concerns decimals so a switch would be impossible i think?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:
**Xaml**

```
<StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelInworp">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0">
                <Button x:Name="btnTweeEuro" Margin="10" MinWidth="220" Content="2" Click="btnGeld_Click"></Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnEenEuro" Margin="10" MinWidth="220" Content="1" Click="btnGeld_Click"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0">
                <Button x:Name="btnVijftigEurocent" Margin="10" MinWidth="100" Content="50" Click="btnGeld_Click"></Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnTwintigEurocent" Margin="10" MinWidth="100" Content="20" Click="btnGeld_Click"></Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnTienEurocent" Margin="10" MinWidth="100" Content="10" Click="btnGeld_Click"></Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnVijfEurocent" Margin="10" MinWidth="100" Content="5" Click="btnGeld_Click"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5">
                <Label Content="Huidige inworp:" MinWidth="160"></Label>
                <Label x:Name="lblHuidigeInworp" Content="" MinWidth="300" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"></Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
```

Code:

```
//Methode voor uitvoeren van alle click events mbt Geld
    private void GeldClick(decimal Inworp)
    {
        TotaalInworp += Inworp;
        lblHuidigeInworp.Content = String.Format("€ {0}", TotaalInworp); 
    }

    //Enkel click event voor alle knoppen mbt Drank
    private void btnGeld_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        switch (btn.Content.ToString())
        {
            case "2":
                GeldClick(2.00M);
                break;
            case "1":
                GeldClick(1.00M);
                break;
            case "50":
                GeldClick(0.50M);
                break;
            case "20":
                GeldClick(0.20M);
                break;
            case "10":
                GeldClick(0.10M);
                break;
            case "5":
                GeldClick(0.05M);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Anyone knows improvements? Wanted to work with the stackpanelname for the buttons but don't know how to ...